# Ist „fein“ auch eine gute Antwort auf „Wie geht es dir?“

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Hallo Steffi, wie geht es dir heute?
>
> Fein, und dir?
>
> Sehr gut, danke.

Kann man *fein* in diesem Kontext verwenden?

Comment: Valid cognate to “How are you?”—“[I’m] fine.”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ja**, man kann auch mit *fein* antworten.

Fein ist einerseits das Gegenteil von grob, wie in *fein gemahlenes Mehl, feiner Zucker, feine Handarbeit, feiner Humor, feinste Brüsseler Spitze* aber ist wohl, weil so oft ein Qualitätsmerkmal, auch als allgemeines Wort für *gut* auf Bereiche adaptiert worden, in denen es die ursprüngliche Bedeutung nicht hat - das ist allerdings meine Spekulation.

"Das hast Du fein gemacht", sagt man beispielsweise auch zu einem Köter, der brav einen Stock apportiert hat.

Comment: "Fein" hat aber auch nocht mehr Bedeutungen, als den Gegensatz zu "grob" auszumachen. So kann es schlicht für "(sehr) gut" im Bezug auf Qualität stehen. So kann eine "feine Handarbeit" zweideutig verstanden werden, wobei genau genommen das eine das andere bedingt (->aus nicht grober Arbeit folgt gute Qualität). Auch "feiner Humor" kann zweideutig interpretiert werden, wenngleich hier natürlich keine Äquivalenz besteht (nicht anzüglich versus anspruchsvoll). Naja, auf jeden Fall ist meine Spekulation, dass es von dem Qualitäts-"fein" abgeleitet ist, nicht von Anti-Grobheit.

Comment: In meinem Umfeld sagen nur Frauen "fein" und das auch nur sehr selten. "Sehr gut" sagen dagegen Männer und Frauen häufiger.

Comment: @Iris: Fein! :)

Comment: @Em1: Ich meine dass eben beides lange Zeit Hand in Hand ging. Der einfache Ritter hatte auch ein verziertes Schwert, aber nicht so fein verziert wie das des Königs. Der Waffenschmied mit den besten Fähigkeiten, dem größten Know-How, der meisten Geduld und Geschicklichkeit usw. wurde auch beauftragt die teuersten Waffen zu schmieden. Mit der Moderne haben sich die Maßstäbe verschoben.

Comment: Eh, nee, "fein" geht meiner Meinung nach nicht als Antwort auf "wie geht es". Da gehen nur "gut" und "schlecht" und alles dazwischen.

Comment: Dieser Gegensatz zwischen *fein* und *Köter* … =C

Answer (score 5):

Das ist möglicherweise auch örtlich bedingt, aber wenn ich es höre kommt es komisch rüber. Also keiner wird sich beschweren und alle werden es verstehen, aber es ist eher ungewöhnlich.

Comment: Ich glaube, dass das nicht nur örtlich, sondern auch sozial bedingt ist. In Wien kann man das »fein« als Antwort durchaus hören, aber eher aus dem Mund der älteren Dame, die im Pelzmantel ins Konzerthaus geht, als vom Arbeiter, der währenddessen genau 20 Meter unter der Dame durch die Kanalisation watet.

Answer (score 1):

**Nein**. Ich habe es noch nie in diesem Zusammenhang gehört. Es klingt als würde jemand versuchen das englische "fine" einzudeutschen.

Wenn "fein" im Sinn von "gut" verwendet wird, passiert das meist bezogen auf Qualität (fein gemacht, feine Handwerksarbeit, ...) im Gegensatz zu grob/schlecht ausgeführter Arbeit. Niemand sagt "Es geht mir fein".